Derived category of $\mathbb A^n/{\mathbb G_m}$
Beilinson proved that the bounded derived category $D^b(\mathbb P^n)=<\mathcal O, \mathcal O(1),...\mathcal O(n)>$ as a semiorthogonal decomposition.

I would like to know what happens for $D^b(\mathbb A^n)$ and  $D^b([\mathbb A^n/{\mathbb G_m}])$?

I know that any coherent sheaf has a resolution by vector bundles on $\mathbb A^n$ and these vector bundles are also all trivial. So is $D^b(\mathbb A^n)=<\mathcal O>$? What about the stack $[\mathbb A^n/{\mathbb G_m}]$?

The derived category of affine space is generated by the structure sheaf, but this sheaf is not exceptional. And what action of the multiplicative group do you have in mind?

By the way, Beilinson didn't quite prove this. He constructed a resolution of the diagonal, but at the time of writing his exceptional objects and exceptional collections were not yet defined.

@Sasha the action is the usual diagonal action by multiplication.
